# Is there any way to access the stroke width (or style) within a SwiftUI view?

Tags: swiftui, shapes, swiftui-environment, swiftui-layout

I want to create a custom `Shape` and give it the same height as its stroke width.

```
struct HorizontalLine: Shape {
        
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        let verticalCenter = rect.height / 2
        var path = Path()
        path.move(to: .init(x: 0, y: verticalCenter))
        path.addLine(to: .init(x: rect.width, y: verticalCenter))
        return path
    }
    
    func sizeThatFits(_ proposal: ProposedViewSize) -> CGSize {
        .init(width: proposal.width, height: lineWidth)
    }                                //      ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑
                                     //  How to obtain this?
}
```

I know that I can wrap that whole view in a `.frame(height: ...)` modifier, but that's not what I want as it would create a redundancy (specify the height in both the stroke width and the height of the container view).

I want the `HorizontalLine` view to be "smart", so that it self-sizes according to the line width as specified in an outer `stroke(lineWidth:)` modifier.

#### Is there any way to access the `lineWidth` from within this shape?

It doesn't seems to be provided by the `@Environment`.

Comment: You could make the linewidth a parameter to the ```Shape``` (say, as a hint). But it would not stop the caller from using a different linewidth when the stroke is actually performed.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Following SwiftUI's core idea, the `stroke` modifier defines the `lineWidth` as the single source of truth. Adding a parameter to `Shape` or even a custom environment key would violate that principle.